# Why if I put odd count of %s in FOR processed items the command exits the script?

Tags: batch-file

Here's an example:

```
@echo off
for /f %%# in ('rem %')  do echo %%#
echo never displayed
```

(and the output is a slightly different with this example - one empty line less is produced - despite the scripts should do the same)

```
@echo off

for /f %%# in ('rem %')  do echo %%#
echo never displayed
```

Though there's no problem if there's no tokens in the DO block:

```
@echo off
for /f %%# in ('rem %')  do dir
echo will be displayed
```

Looks like the script tries to expand some variable when meets `%` but it is somehow interrupted by the closing bracket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a parser error while trying to interpret the line

```
for /f %%# in ('rem %') do echo %%#
                    ^...........^
                    undefined variable

for /f %%# in ('rem %') do dir
                    ^
                    without a closing percent sign, it is discarded
```

Try with (this fails the same)

```
for /f %%# in ('echo yes ^& rem %') do echo %%#
```

And now with

```
set "') do echo =') do echo %%"
for /f %%# in ('echo yes ^& rem %') do echo %%#
echo displayed
```

**edited** after some more test it seems the problem has not relation to the `for` command but to a search of a right closing parenthesis that ends in a wrong error handling that discards all the commands parsed inside the non closed code block.

This batch file (those are all the lines in it)

```
if 1==1 (
    for %a in (test) do echo %%a
```

will fail with a syntax error (`%a`) showing that the parser is processing it, but if the error is corrected

```
if 1==1 (
    for %%a in (test) do echo %%a
```

the batch ends without any error

Just a simple batch as this, without the `if` or `for` parser differences, behaves the same

```
( echo test
```

Comment: despite for sure it fails to expand a variable still is strange that it exists from the script instead of just print an error. But this one more of these things that we cant know more without seeing the cmd.exe source code.

Comment: @npocmaka, answer edited. Not much more information on why, only when.

Answer (score 1):

The '%' character must be escaped with another '%' character. Must you use '#' for a variable name? Will [a-z] not work for you?

```
@echo off
for /f %%# in ('rem %%')  do echo %%#
echo never displayed
```

Comment: I'm aware hot to escape the `%` . Though the `FOR` should not exit the entire script - this does not happen with `IF` for example which have similar parser...